# Questions on creating Classes & Methods and on accessing these Methods from a Form

Tags: c#, winforms, class, methods

Im sure that plenty of you on here will find it fairly simple to do this so an explanation of a few things would be cool. This is an assignment for an intro cs class so the simplest solution will suffice. The goal is to create a token machine class and the methods within. Then to access those methods in a Windows Form app. The form app has 2 text boxes, one for number of quarters and the other for number of tokens and 2 buttons. The first being a Get Token button which will add one to the quarter value and subtract one from the token value. The second is a Reset button which will set the value of quarters to 0 and tokens to 100.

```
       using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace TokenMachine
 {
     public partial class Form1 : Form
     {

         // class level reference to a token machine
         private TokenMachine tm;
         public Form1()
         {
             // create a token machine object
             InitializeComponent();
             tm = new TokenMachine();
             tm.Reset();
```

At this point i create the class TokenMachine, no issues there
             }

```
         private void exitToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

         }

         private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

         }

         private void buttonGetToken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

         }

         private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

         {

         }
    }
 }
```

After creating the class I am left with some confusion. I will post my UML Class Diagram for further clarity.

```
     ![TokenMachine UML Diagram][1]
```

This is what ive got so far.

This is not an answer i just didn't know where to post the rest. I was apparently having some formatting issues.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

        namespace TokenMachine
{
    class TokenMachine
    {

        private int numTokens = 0;
        private int numQuarters = 0;
```

Now I create a constructor to initialize the Data Members of TokenMachien

```
 public TokenMachine()
{
    numTokens = 100;
    numQuarters = 0;
}
```

Now for the GetToken Method. My confusion here is what exactly should this method look like. Again this method will add 1 quarter and subtract one token.

```
public int? void? GetToken(are there parameters required for this type of method?)
{
}
```

Next we have the CountTokens method which returns the number of tokens that are in the machine. public ???? CountTokens(??, ??) { }

CountQuarters method which returns the number of quarters that are in the machine.

```
public ???? CountQuarters(??, ??)
{
}
```

finally the Reset method which removes all of the quarters and fills the machine with tokens. For this class we will assume that the machine holds 100 tokens.

```
public ???? Reset(??, ??)?????????
{
????????????????????????????
}
```

This is my first time creating a class and the methods within. Accessing the methods from my form does not seem to pose a problem as i have done this before.
What is the correct format for writing these methods. Ie GetToken() CountTokens() CountQUarters() and mostly **Reset()**

Comment: you forgot to ask a question?

Comment: GetTokens would probably be an int return type, i don't see why you would need any parameters there. Reset seems to be a void (or are you expecting a value to be returned?), CountTokens will also return 1 (though you might simply use a public int Property for it), CountQuarters is the same. As long as you also update the values for your texdtboxes after every change, i don't see a problem :) You should probably convert the values to string to put them into your textboxes...

Comment: Reset should bring the Token value back to 100 and the quarter value back to 0. Whats the easiest way to update the values of my text boxes  every change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void GetToken()
{
    numQuarters++; // ++ 'is increase by one', guess what -- will do
    numTokens--;
}
public int CountTokens()
{
    return numTokens;
}
public void Reset()
{
    numQuarters = 0;
    numTokens = 100;
}
```

FYIs `void` means do not return a value from this method, replacing the `void` with a type `int, string, double, Object, Form` is return this type from the method.

```
     private void buttonGetToken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         tm.GetToken();
     }

     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

     {
         TheNameOfYuorTextBox.Text = tm.CountTokens().ToString();
     }
```

EDIT:

The edits that you suggested. Calling `tm.GetTokens()` and `tm.GetQuaters()` without assigning the value that they return to anything, is pointless.
And creating a new `TokenMachine`, then calling 'Reset' is pointless if the `TokenMachine` constructor sets the values anyway.

To use breakpoints, click the margin so the red dot appears, inside one of your button click methods, then launch and click the button. The entire program will pause on that one line of code (but not do that line of code), then you can inspect the values of the variables, right click and say `QuickWatch` or hovering over the variable.

Comment: from method name of GetToken, i would expect you also Get the token (so a void seems inappropriate for this method, as you are getting nothing)

Comment: His Spec does not mention this method doing anything other than increment and decrement

Comment: The get token is in reference to the user inserting a quarter into the machine and getting a token. Unimportant to the exercise, all that is needed is the number of quarters and tokens in the machine.

Comment: @ColinSteel thank you this is exactly what i was looking for. For some reason I thought there was a lot more to it than that which seemed to throw me off. Anyway thanks again.

Comment: Hmmm the get token button does not seem to be working

Comment: GetTokenButton not working cos you can see any thing happening?
To change the text of the number of tokens/quarters you will need to call that method again.
Do you know how to use breakpoints?

Comment: I know how to place a breakpoint through my own exploring of visualstudio but no i don't know how to use it.